# Jest Unit tests for High order component containing Block Editor

Tags: javascript, block-editor, testing, unit-tests

everyone!

I created High order component HOC which adds additional panel to Advanced section at the right sidebar
Something like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

import {InspectorAdvancedControls} from '@wordpress/block-editor'
import {hasBlockSupport} from '@wordpress/blocks'
import {Notice, ExternalLink} from '@wordpress/components'
import {createHigherOrderComponent} from '@wordpress/compose'
import {useSelect} from '@wordpress/data'
import {addFilter} from '@wordpress/hooks'

export const WithInspectorAdvancedControls = createHigherOrderComponent<InnerComponent, OuterComponent>(
  BlockEdit => props => {
    const {name, attributes, isSelected} = props
    if (!hasBlockSupport(name, 'custom-name')) {
      return <BlockEdit {...props} />
    }
    const currentPost = useSelect(select => select('core/editor'))

    return (
      <>
        {isSelected && (
          <InspectorAdvancedControls>
            <div>
                <Notice status="warning" isDismissible={false}>Notice</Notice>
                <ExternalLink href={attributes.link}>{attributes.link}</ExternalLink>
            </div>
          </InspectorAdvancedControls>
        )}
        <BlockEdit {...props} />
      </>
    )
  },
  'WithInspectorAdvancedControls'
)

addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'module/name', WithInspectorAdvancedControls)
```

Now I need to test it.
Can you explain me or give an example how to mock blockEditor and what are the common approach in testing HOC (for example, should test somehow filtering).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you mean `BlockEdit` rather than `BlockEditor`? I suspect that's what you meant but `BlockEditor` and `BlockEdit` are very different things. Also what about it are you trying to test? Is it really necessary to have everything in the one single component instead of using a second component that can be tested?

Comment: @TomJNowell! yes, I mean exactly BlockEdit. 

Here (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) from Wordpress documentation you can that this is Block Filter that allow us to modify block’s edit component.
I'm trying to test
1. render `BlockEdit` without crashing
2. render only `BlockEdit` (without  `InspectorAdvancedControls`) if current block doesn't support the 'custom-name' or current block is not selected
3. rendering `BlockEdit` without `InspectorAdvancedControls` if current block is selected and support the 'custom-name'